# 410 gone error response from IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-410

I've recently come accross an issue with IIS responding with a 410 status code when a request query string exceeds 500 characters.

The application is an asp.net web app using the classic managaged pipline.

I've already tried increasing the maxRequestLength, maxUrlLength, and maxQueryStringLength to their max of 2097151 to no avail.

I don't understand why the server would respond with a 410 status code.

Any help would or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am facing similar issue but not sure if i get this error because of request query string length.